# How to divide an unknown integer into a given number of (almost) even integers

Tags: javascript

I need help with the ability to divide an unknown integer into a given number of even parts — or at least as even as they can be. The sum of the parts should be the original value, but each part should be an integer, and they should be as close as possible.

Parameters
num: Integer - The number that should be split into equal parts

parts: Integer - The number of parts that the number should be split 
into

Return Value
List (of Integers) - A list of parts, with each index representing the part and the number contained within it representing the size of the part. The parts will be ordered from smallest to largest.

this is what I have

```js
var splitInteger = function(num, parts) {
  // Complete this function

  var randombit = num * parts;
  var out = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    out.push(Math.random());
  }

  var mult = randombit / out.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });

  return out.map(function(el) {
    return el * mult;
  });

}
var d = splitInteger(10, 5)
console.log(d);
console.log("sum - " + d.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b
}));
```

This is the sample tests

```
let assert = require("chai").assert;
describe('Challenge', function() {
  it('Simple Functionality', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(10,1), [10]);
    assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(2,2), [1,1]);
    assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(20,5), [4,4,4,4,4]);
  });
});
```

**Examples of the expected output:**

num parts   Return Value.

Completely even parts example   10  5   [2,2,2,2,2].

Even as can be parts example    20  6   [3,3,3,3,4,4].

I am getting an error.

Comment: How do you want to determine what 'even as can be' means? For instance, why would `20, 6` return `3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4` and not `4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2` ?

Comment: @OliverRadini : I believe, it's the difference between parts - in your example it's 1 and 2, so the former is preferable.

Comment: It did, Thanks alot guys

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
var splitInteger = function(num, parts) {
  // Complete this function

  var val;
  var mod = num % parts;
  if(mod == 0){
    val = num/parts;
    retData = Array(parts).fill(val);
  } else {
    val = (num-mod)/parts;
    retData = Array(parts).fill(val);
    for(i=0;i<mod;i++){
      retData[i] = retData[i] + 1;
    }
    retData.reverse()
  }

  return retData;

}
var d = splitInteger(20, 6)
console.log(d);
console.log("sum - " + d.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b}));
```

Comment: "The parts will be ordered from smallest to largest."

Answer (score 13):

You may get maximum integer coefficient as `x/y` rounded down to integer and remainder with `x%y`. Than simply break remainder into 1's and add those 1's to corresponding number of parts:

```js
const breakIntoParts = (num, parts) => 
        [...Array(parts)].map((_,i) => 
          0|num/parts+(i < num%parts))

console.log(JSON.stringify(breakIntoParts(20, 6)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

Comment: Does this always work? I tried with `21` and `6` and it gave `[
  4,
  4,
  4,
  5,
  5,
  5
]`

Comment: It sums to `27`, the question states `The sum of the parts should be the original value`

Answer (score 3):

Extremely simple solution:

```js
const splitInteger = (number, parts) => {
    const remainder = number % parts
    const baseValue = (number - remainder) / parts

    return Array(parts).fill(baseValue).fill(baseValue + 1, parts - remainder)
}
```

To order from largest to smallest:

```js
const splitInteger = (number, parts) => {
    const remainder = number % parts
    const baseValue = (number - remainder) / parts

    return Array(parts).fill(baseValue).fill(baseValue + 1, 0, remainder)
}
```

Now as an npm module: [split-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split-integer)

Comment: How do we know we can do `baseValue + 1` and it will work? What is the math/reasoning behind this?

Comment: First, we evenly distribute the number across each item. Then for the leftover amount, we spread it out among as many items as needed. For example: Split 9 over 6 items. First, we fill the array with [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], leaving us with a leftover of 3 that doesn't evenly fit. Now, we spread it among just 3 items, causing those values to increase by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck for a while on this problem and previous answers did not work for cases which I needed. This solutions worked for cases I needed to :

```
function splitInteger(num, parts) {
    let fractions = Array(parts).fill(num);
    let addedFractionsInst = addedFractions(fractions, parts);
    let integerPartsOfFractionsInst = integerPartsOfFractions(addedFractionsInst, parts);
    let pairWiseDifferenceInst = pairWiseDifference(integerPartsOfFractionsInst, parts);
    return pairWiseDifferenceInst.sort((a, b) => (a-b));
}

function addedFractions(array, parts) {
    let newArray = Array(parts);
    newArray[0] = array[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = newArray[i-1] + array[0];
    }
    return newArray;
}

function integerPartsOfFractions(array, parts) {
    let newArray = Array(parts);
    for (let i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
        newArray[i] = Math.trunc(array[i]/parts);
    }
    return newArray;
}

function pairWiseDifference(array, parts) {
    let newArray = Array(parts);
    newArray[0] = array[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[i] - array[i - 1];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Implemented based on user65203 solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791795/dividing-an-integer-into-a-fixed-number-of-integers/1791823#1791823?newreg=5fd1fc55a01d45c7a26fcb385170f65d

Works for :

```
const splitInteger = require('..');
const assert = require('assert')

assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(10,1), [10]);
assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(2, 2), [1,1]);
assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(20,5), [4,4,4,4,4]);
assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(10,4), [2, 2, 3, 3]);
assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(7,4), [1, 2, 2, 2]);
assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(10,8), [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]);
assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(20,6), [3,3,3,3,4,4]);
assert.deepEqual(splitInteger(21,6), [ 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ]);
```