# Assign a list of items a number (up to 50) in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of items in column C that I would like to assign a different number value. An example list would look like:

| Column C (Before) | Column C (After) |
| --- | --- |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Orange |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Orange |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Apple 0 |  |
| Orange |  |
| Orange |  |

It will assign "1" up until it reaches a **maximum of 50** in the list.

For example, if there is under 50 "Apple 0" it will just do "Apple 1". But if there is more than 50, it will split evenly, "Apple 1" and "Apple 2".

In other words:

- If less than 50 zeros are found, it automatically assigns the value
  "1" (Apple 0 --> Apple 1).
- If greater than 50 but less than 100 zeros are found, it
  automatically assigns the values "1" and "2" evenly (Apple 0 -->
  Apple 1 x 50, Apple 2 x 50).
- If greater than 100 but less than 150 zeros are found, it
  automatically assigns the values "1" "2" and "3" evenly.
- If greater than 150 but less than 200 zeros are found, it
  automatically assigns the values "1" "2" "3" and "4" evenly, and so
  on.

I am trying to trigger this function from the menu with:

```
function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

    ui.createMenu('Assign Values')
        .addItem('Assign Numbers to Zeroes (Max. 50)', 'assignNumbers')
        .addToUi();
}


function assignNumbers() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var colC = sheet.getRange("C:C");
    var colCValues = colC.getValues();

    var appleCount = 0; // to store the apple count
    var appleLineAddress = []; // to store the row-no of Apple 0's

    // get the total count and and its row-no

    for (let i = 0; i < colCValues.length; i++) {
        if (colCValues[i][0] == "") continue;
        if (colCValues[i][0].toString().includes('Apple 0')) {
            appleCount++;
            appleLineAddress.push(i);
        }
    }

    // Check apple count and divide 

    if (appleCount < 50) {

        for (let i = 0; i < appleLineAddress.length; i++) {
            sheet.getRange(i + 5, 3).setValue('Apple 1');
        }

    } else if (appleCount > 50 && appleCount <= 100) {
        printAppleCount(2, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 100 && appleCount <= 150) {
        printAppleCount(3, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 150 && appleCount <= 200) {
        printAppleCount(4, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 200 && appleCount <= 250) {
        printAppleCount(5, appleCount, appleLineAddress);

    } else if (appleCount > 250 && appleCount <= 300) {
        printAppleCount(6, appleCount, appleLineAddress);
    }

}



function printAppleCount(caseNo, appleCount, appleLineAddress) {

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var splitInteger = function numParts(num, parts) {
    var val;
    var mod = num % parts;
    if (mod == 0) {
        val = num / parts;
        retData = Array(parts).fill(val);
    } else {
        val = (num - mod) / parts;
        retData = Array(parts).fill(val);
        for (i = 0; i < mod; i++) {
            retData[i] = retData[i] + 1;
        }
        retData.reverse()
        //Comment the above line to unreverse the result.
    }
    return retData;
}

    console.log("Case No: " + caseNo);
    console.log("AppleCount : " + appleCount);
    var equalSplits = splitInteger(appleCount, caseNo);

    console.log(equalSplits);

    // for the applecount: 113(suppose), the var equalSplits will log [37,38,38].
    // You can print the data now with the equalSplits and appleLineAddress

    var k = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < equalSplits.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < equalSplits[i]; j++) {
            console.log('Print Apple ' + (i + 1) + ' at ' + appleLineAddress[k++]);
            sheet.getRange(appleLineAddress[k++], 3).setValue('Apple ' + (i + 1));

        }
    }

}
```

**Error:** Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.

The result is skipping numbers rather than assigning properly. See console log results:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| May 13, 2021, 5:21:59 PM | Debug | Case No: 2 |
| May 13, 2021, 5:21:59 PM Debug | AppleCount : 52 |  |
| May 13, 2021, 5:21:59 PM Debug | [ 26, 26 ] |  |
| May 13, 2021, 5:21:59 PM Debug | Print Apple 1 at 6 |  |
| May 13, 2021, 5:21:59 PM Debug | Print Apple 1 at 8 |  |
| May 13, 2021, 5:21:59 PM Debug | Print Apple 1 at 10 |  |
| May 13, 2021, 5:21:59 PM Debug | Print Apple 1 at 12 |  |
| May 13, 2021, 5:21:59 PM Debug | Print Apple 1 at 14 |  |
| etc... | ... |  |

We're almost there, it's just jumping 6, 8, 10 etc. -- but it's splitting batches equally which is a good sign.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your table the sample input situation? If it's so, in order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample output situation you expect? Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot image your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I agree with @Tanaike, Can you please provide an output column or an image or anything actually to show what you actually want.

Comment: Also, can you please share the code(what have you tried so far)? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Tanaike and JustCurious - I have added an example second column. Basically clicking the menu button will trigger it so that it finds any "Apple 0" and replaces the 0 with 1. If there are 100 "Apple 0" it will do 50 "Apple 1" (max) and 50 "Apple 2". If there are 75 "Apple 0" it will split evenly 37 "Apple 1" and 37 "Apple 2". If there are 150 "Apple 0" it will do 50 "Apple 1" 50 "Apple 2" and 50 "Apple 3" -- it basically does a batch of 50 assignments, labeling them 1, 2, 3, 4. It specifically targets "Apple 0".

Comment: I think I got a clue of what you want, but have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @JustCurious I've included a mess of a first attempt, the gist of it is there but it's definitely missing components. Thank you!

Comment: `If there are 75 "Apple 0" it will split evenly 37 "Apple 1" and 37 "Apple 2".`. 37 times 2 is 74, in other words you cannot split 75 evenly in two (for integers). Would you like to split it in 38, 37 or the opposite?

Comment: It is unclear why you want to do this with a script when the problem seems simple enough  to solve with a spreadsheet array formula. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with a reasonable amount of realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I notices that the discussions have already been advanced and an answer has already ben posted. In this case, I would like to respect them.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that as @doubleunary states, this is a simple enough task and spreadsheet formulas can do the magic. But if your case is something more than what you described then here is something to start with:

```
  var colA = sheet.getRange("A:A"); 
  var colAValues = colA.getValues();
  
  var appleCount = 0;         // to store the apple count
  var appleLineAddress = [];  // to store the row-no of 'Apple 0's.

  // get the total count and and its row-no
  for(let i=0; i<colAValues.length; i++){
    if(colAValues[i][0] == "") continue;
    if(colAValues[i][0].toString().includes('Apple'))
    {
      appleCount++;
      appleLineAddress.push(i);
    }
  } 
  
  // Check apple Count and Divide 
  if(appleCount < 50)
  {
    for(let i = 0; i<appleLineAddress.length; i++)
    {
      sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue('Apple 1');
    }
  } 
  else if(appleCount >= 50 && appleCount <100)
  {
    printAppleCount(2,appleCount,appleLineAddress);    
  } 
  else if(appleCount >= 100 && appleCount <150)
  {
    printAppleCount(3,appleCount,appleLineAddress)
  } 
  else if(appleCount >= 150 && appleCount <200)
  {
    printAppleCount(4,appleCount,appleLineAddress);
  }
  else ...
```

I have used [this answer's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56107897/11795828) to equally distribute the no between your said cases(1,2,3,4,...)

```
var splitInteger = function(num, parts) {
   var val;
  var mod = num % parts;
  if(mod == 0){
    val = num/parts;
    retData = Array(parts).fill(val);
  } else {
    val = (num-mod)/parts;
    retData = Array(parts).fill(val);
    for(i=0;i<mod;i++){
      retData[i] = retData[i] + 1;
    }
    retData.reverse()
    //Comment the above line to unreverse the result.
  }
  return retData;
}
```

and then you just need to print:

```
function printAppleCount(caseNo, appleCount, appleLineAddress){
  console.log("Case No: "+caseNo);
  console.log("AppleCount : "+appleCount);
  var equalSplits = splitInteger(appleCount, caseNo);
  
  console.log(equalSplits);
  // for the applecount : 113(suppose), the var equalSplits will log [37,38,38].

  // You can print the data now with the equalSplits and appleLineAddress
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Obviously, you can use a lot of one-liner functions for most of the code mentioned above. The above code is just to maintain readability.

If I misunderstood your question or this is not what you wanted, I apologize.

### Edit After Comment

- **Apple 1 in Adjacent Column:** I am using `sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue('Apple 1');` for your understanding so that the adjacent column gets the value.

You can simply change the `col address in getRange()` to `(i+2,3) //or whatever your column index is.`

- **printAppleCount()** : This function is to print the values into required parts. You have `equalSplits (an array of [37,38,38] )` and also have the `lineAddresses(the row no. which had 'Apple 0')`. You can loop through the values to print the Apple 1/2/3 with the exact count. And, The `appleLineAddress` will take care of the mixed data i.e. Apple, Orange, Strawberry, and then again Apple,...

Code:

```
var k = 0;
for(var i=0; i<equalSplits.length; i++){
 for(var j=0; j<equalSplits[i]; j++)
 {
  console.log('Print Apple '+(i+1)+' at'+appleLineAddress[k++]);
  sheet.getRange(appleLineAddress[k++],3).setValue('Apple '+(i+1)); 
 }
}
```

Also, please refer to [the Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) for better understanding. Cheers!

Comment: If this answer somehow helped you, please think about upvoting it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this! Just a few things. Apple 0s will be replaced cell by cell, as opposed to being produced in the column adjacent. So if there's an Apple 0, it will become Apple 1. The reason why I can't use formulas is because the Apple 0s are the result of a formula themselves. The script will then replace the 0s with 1s and 2s and 3s evenly distributed at a max of 50 per number. Also, can you explain how the printAppleCount part works? Also the target will be column C (I guess we can use range C:C) or point to 3 and get last row? Whatever is efficient. Do I point to printAppleCount in UI?

Comment: Also, another issue is that it should correspond to each "Apple 0" accordingly. When it splits values and assigns 1/2/3 for different batches, it should replace the zeroes with those 1/2/3 and not in the column to the right of it. Likewise, the table may not just be a straight list of "Apple 0" but may have "Orange" or "Strawberry" mixed it. So it should be targeting "Apple 0" and then replacing the 0 with a 1 up to a max of 50.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please see the **Edit After Comment** in the answer now. And please use the Tickmart to mark this as an answer as the edit should do what you desire.

Comment: Hi JustCurious, I've updated the code I'm working with in the main post. I'm getting the following error:  Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.

Comment: I've figured out the problem. I had to add +1 here: appleLineAddress.push(i+1); 
 I also had to remove the k++ here: sheet.getRange(appleLineAddress[k], 3).setValue('Apple ' + (i + 1));

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
=INDEX(IF(COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")<50, SUBSTITUTE(A:A, "Apple 0", "Apple 1"), 
 IF((COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")>=50 )*(COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")<100)*(A:A="Apple 0"), "Apple "&1+INT((COUNTIFS(A:A, A:A, A:A, "Apple 0", ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A:A))-1)/(COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")/2)), 
 IF((COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")>=100)*(COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")<150)*(A:A="Apple 0"), "Apple "&1+INT((COUNTIFS(A:A, A:A, A:A, "Apple 0", ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A:A))-1)/(COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")/3)), 
 IF((COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")>=150)*(COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")<200)*(A:A="Apple 0"), "Apple "&1+INT((COUNTIFS(A:A, A:A, A:A, "Apple 0", ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A:A))-1)/(COUNTIFS(A:A, "Apple 0")/4)), A:A)))))
```

[image]